# Virtualbox Performance Discrepancy: Desktop vs Laptop

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am noticing significant performance discrepancies when using virtualbox on my desktop vs laptop. Performance is much slower on my laptop: not just boot/shutdown but also building my Docker BE or Angular FE (Angular FE being especially slow to build: 25-35 sec on Desktop vs 2.5-3.5 min on Laptop).

Both systems are running `Virtualbox 6.1.5` and the same `Debian Buster 64` virtual client. Both *clients* have identical specs (running on different hardware though):

- 2 CPUs (`Desktop: 8 cores, 8 threads, 3.6GHz base  - Laptop: 4 cores, 8 threads, 2.9GHz base`)
- 4GB Ram (`Desktop: 32GB, 3000MHz, CL15  - Laptop: 16GB, 2400MHz, CL16`)
- 30GB Storage (`Desktop: Located on a SATA III SSD  - Laptop: Located on a HDD`)

My first guess would be SSD vs HDD might be the explanation (especially for boot). But I don't know that it explains other programs being slower and I'm having a hard time imagining the different CPUs/RAMs could explain such difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your laptop has an HDD, disk IO is almost always the first bottleneck in VMs.  HDDs are noticeably slower than SDDs, especially when you factor in 2 OSes running on one spindle.  SSDs don't suffer here.  Your laptop CPU is ~20% slower also based purely on Ghz (could be more if they're different models and generations), so while you've got the same number of vCPUs assigned, they're running slower on the laptop.  Memory access is also slower, which will in turn, slow down your VM.  Everything is slower on your laptop.

Comment: @essjae Thanks, so maybe the main bottleneck is indeed the HDD. However, I should note that my Host OS on my laptop runs on a PCIe Gen 3 - only the VM runs on the HDD (space being tight I couldn't run it on the SSD). So at least the *2 OS* issue should be negligible.